# Ошибка: для индекса требуется массив или указатель C++

Tags: c++

Вот пример на котором у меня происходит подобное:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class key, class value> //пара с двумя параметрами - ключ и значение
struct pairs 
{
    key Key;
    value Value;
};

template<class key, class value>
struct test
{
    pairs<key, value>* arr; //указатель для массива пар.
    test(const size_t& size) //выделяю памяти для массива пар
    {
        arr = new pairs<key, value>[size]; 
    }
    value& operator[](const key& key) //возвращаю ЗНАЧЕНИЕ
    {
        return arr->Value[key]; //<=== ошибка всплывает тут
    }
};

int main()
{
    test<int, int> Example(100);
    Example[0] = 0;
    cout << Example[0];
}
```

С чем связана данная ошибка и как можно ее исправить в моем случае?

Comment: `value& operator[](const key& k)
    {
        return arr[k].Value; 
    }`

Comment: однако массив не инициализирован....

Comment: . key это ключ, а  arr это массив,  нельзя вместо смещения указателя использовать ключ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выполните анализ того, что хотите делать:

1. Вряд ли `struct pairs`  еще где понадобится(поскольку есть
   std::pair), кроме как структуре `test`, поэтому лучше пусть pairs
   будет вложенным классом, чтобы "под ногами не валялся".
2. Конструктор `test` принимает размер и создает массив такого размера,
   где хранятся пары. Однако эти пары не инициализированы, а значит
   нарушается инвариант(свойство объектов иметь определенное
   состояние). Конструктор должен их как то инициализировать или это
   должен делать конструктор этих объектов.
3. Для того, чтобы `operator[]` принимал ключ и возвращал
   соответствующее значение(создание ассоциативности), нужно найти в
   массиве элемент с таким ключом и возвращать его значение(как
   подсказал αλεχολυτ, не получится, индексом для массива может быть только целочисленный тип). А если такого нет? Что делать
   тогда, решать вам. Я думаю, что нужно тогда инициализировать первый
   же элемент, имеющий значения по умолчанию и инициализировать его
   данным ключом. А если в массиве все элементы уже инициализированы,
   тогда или пусть, например, оператор ничего не делает. Естественно,
   что реализовав ассоциативный массив посредством простого массива,
   создаст проблемы такого рода и в быстродействии, но для малых задач
   покатит...